# Struts2 checkbox preselect

Tags: struts2

I am creating checkbox inside iterator.  Below are my code,

```
<s:iterator value="contacts" var="contact">
    <tr>
       <td>
        <s:checkbox name="selectContactsCheckBox" fieldValue="%{#contact.contactid}" value="%{defaultContacts.contains(contact.contactid)}" theme="simple"/>
       </td>
       <td>${contact.fullname}</td>
       <td>${contact.mobile}</td>
       <td>${contact.organization}</td>
       <td>${contact.department}</td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

this code creates checkbox and works fine. But i want to preselect this checkboxes using a collection from action.

Below is a method from my action calss,

```
public List<String> getDefaultContacts() {
    return Arrays.asList(this.selectedContacts);
}
```

suppose if i have 100 contact in list and if getDefaultConatacs() return just 5 string then i want to select those 5 checkbox u

Comment: My problem is resolved. i used the value attribute of checkbox tas as below,       <s:checkbox name="selectContactsCheckBox" fieldValue="%{contactid}"  value="%{contactid in defaultContacts}" theme="simple"></s:checkbox>

Answer (score 2):

If i use below line(value attributes check whether the contactid is available in list)

```xml
<s:checkbox name="selectContactsCheckBox" 
            fieldValue="%{contactid}"
            value="%{contactid in defaultContacts}" 
            theme="simple">
</s:checkbox>
```