# Default state for a checkbox in struts 2

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, taglib

I have a list of checkboxes like this:

```
<s:iterator value="beans">

    <s:set name="currentIdChain" value="%{idChain}"/>

    <s:checkbox name = "selectedItems" 
               value = "%{#currentIdChain in selectedItems}" 
          fieldValue = "%{#currentIdChain}"
            cssClass = "checkbox" />

</s:iterator>
```

and an action like this:

```
public class MyAction {

    private String[] selectedItems;
    private ArrayList<MyBeans> beans;

    //Public getters and setters
}
```

I can get my checkboxes' values with my action, but, if I check one of them, it is not checked by default anymore. So I'd like my checkboxes to be checked if I checked them previously; before execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 checkbox preselect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555052/struts2-checkbox-preselect)

Comment: Try changing from `String[]` to `List<String>`

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran he/she is already doing what that answer suggests, but it's not working, then this is another problem, not solvable by simply reading that solution

Comment: @AndreaLigios : How do you know OP is `she`? Wondering!!!!

Comment: Ahah, edited to include more options :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios Do I have to change my `String[]` to `List`? Cause I have a lot of functions using Object and, if I use `List<String>`, I face: `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.XWorkList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Comment: Can you try to see if the problem is there ? Just create a new list aside the existing String array...

Comment: How many checkboxes you have the list object is returned and it provides the state of the checkboxes. Make a simple change and don't use heavy expressions if you aren't comfortable with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay I have same requirement like this .. I have done something like this

If you want to check them by default if they checked previously .... I have included in my bean class another property of `boolean` type so when I set the data Into bean objects I will check for the Checking status if it is checked i will set `boolean property to true` if it is not I will check that to `false`

So when In JSP

```
     <s:set name="currentIdChain" value="%{idChain}"/>

     <s:checkbox name = "selectedItems" 
            value="%{#attr.current.status}"
      fieldValue = "%{#currentIdChain}"
        cssClass = "checkbox" />

  </s:iterator>
```

`status` here is the state of check box as mentioned above